# Getting class property by name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, casting

I'm overriding the ValidateEntity method to check for unique validation and I've hit a stumbling block.

```
protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
{
    var result = new DbEntityValidationResult(entityEntry, new List<DbValidationError>());

    if (entityEntry.Entity is ReferenceType && entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
    {
        var entity = entityEntry.Entity as ReferenceType;

        var pluralService = PluralizationService.CreateService(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-gb"));
        var pluralEntity = pluralService.Pluralize(entity.GetType().Name);

        // I would like Courses to be replaced with the property name of pluralEntity
        if (Courses.Where(x => x.Title == entity.Title).Count() > 0)
        {
            result.ValidationErrors.Add(new DbValidationError(nameof(entity.Title), nameof(entity.Title) + " must be unique."));
        }
    }

    if (result.ValidationErrors.Count > 0)
    {
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);
    }
}
```

In my SchoolContext class I have the property `DbSet<Course> Courses` which is a ReferenceType (a custom abstract class type).

The value of `pluralEntity` is Courses, but I want to put in the if-statement something similar to:

```
if (Property(pluralEntity).Where(x => x.Title == entity.Title).Count() > 0)
{
    // validate
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

**Update**
I've got this:

```
var prop = (DbSet<ReferenceType>) GetType().GetProperty(pluralEntity).GetValue(this, null);

if (prop.Where(x => x.Title == entity.Title).Count() > 0)
{
    result.ValidationErrors.Add(new DbValidationError(nameof(entity.Title), nameof(entity.Title) + " must be unique."));
}
```

But because `ReferenceType` is an abstract class it cannot cast it at runtime.

I'd like to do something like this

```
var prop = (DbSet<typeof(entityEntry.Entity.GetType().Name)>)
```

But of course that's a variable and can't be passed in as a generic type

Comment: So you want this method to be able to look for duplicates in any `DbSet` for duplicates depending on the type of the entity that's being validated ?

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Will you always use `Title` for the verification?

Comment: Yes, it'll only ever use Title to validate against.

Comment: The only problem I'll probably get is with the ReferenceType class as it's an abstract class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of at the moment is writing a custom validation method, using the repository pattern.

First, create an interface which all your entities will implement

```
public interface IEntity
{
    public string Title {get; set; }
}
```

Then create the repository:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity: class, IEntity
{
    private YourContext context = new YourContext();
    private DbSet<TEntity> AppDbSet;

    public Repository()
    {
        AppDbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    //a couple of method to retrieve data...
    public List<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return AppDbSet.ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
    {
        return AppDbSet.Where<TEntity>(predicate);
    }

    public TEntity Single(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
    {
        return AppDbSet.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }

    //Lastly, implement a validation method
    public bool IsValid(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (AppDbSet.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Title == entity.Title) != null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Use the repository as follow:

```
Repository<Course> courseRepository = new Repository<Course>();

Course course = new Course();
course.Title = "Boring course";

Console.WriteLine(courseRepository.IsValid(course));
```

Hope it helps.